# LINQ to Entiites, left outer join of a group by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I can build a SQL query easily that does the following.

For each row of 'Table1' I want a count of the number of related 'Table2' records that have a 'Status' not equal to 5. There might be no matches so I use a 'left outer join' and then within that use a 'group by' in order to find the total number of matches.

The following query works as SQL. It outputs either a null for the count because there are no matches at all or an actual integer count if there is at least one match.

```
select
    Table1.Id,
    Table2Outer.Count
from
    Table1
    left outer join
    (
        select
            Table2.Id,
            COUNT(*) as Count
        from
            Table2
        where
            Table2.Status != 5
        group by
            Table2.Id
    ) as Table2Outer on Table2Outer.Id = Table.Id
```

Unfortunately I cannot work out how to convert this to LINQ to Entities. The following does not even compile and I am stuck!

```
var x = (from t1 in ctx.Table1
         join t2 in ctx.Table2 on { t1.Id, t2.Status } equals new { t2.Id, Status != 5 } into t2Outer
         from t2OuterB in t2Outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
         group t2Outer by ?);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a navigation property to `Table2` on `Table1`? If so, this gets significanly easier.

Comment: Yes, Table1 entity has a navigation called Table2s of type HashSet<Table2>.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the code more. That Table2s is not a navigable property. So looks like I cannot use the good answer you have already made.Sorry.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: If you rewrite the SQL as `SELECT Table1.Id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id = Table1.Id AND Table2.Status <> 5) AS [Count] FROM Table1` ... does it produce the same results as your original query? It looks like the outer join is a little overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes that would also work, but I have no idea how to do that in Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to count child records in the projection.

```cs
var x = from t1 in ctx.Table1
        select new
        {
            t1.Id,
            Count = (from t2 in ctx.Table2
                     where t2.Status != 5
                     where t2.Id == t1.Id
                     select t2).Count()
        };
```